# Dynamic Div legnth for extended text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a basic show more button for run off text on my site template I'm making, but when it extends it extends over the already established div's. What I want is for when the the show more is active the container div, extends to fit it. What's the best course of action to tackle this?
Here is a js fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/dzhoeo69/

```
html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sea Fusion LLC</title>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubblegum+Sans|Fontdiner+Swanky|Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="clearfix">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-main">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          <div class="header-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- closes the header main -->
            <div class="main-body-background">
                   <div class="main-body-slideshow">

                     <div class="main-boddy-twitter">




                     </div> <!-- close twitter-->


                   </div> <!-- closese the slideshow pannel-->   


      <div class="main-boddy-descript">

          <div class="comment more">
                  Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina
                  Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina 

          <span class="moreelipses" style="display: inline;">...</span>&nbsp;

          <span class="morecontent"><span style="display: none;">Abittia,
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina 
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina 
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina 
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina 
            Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina Abittia es amu regina
          </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div> <!--comment more section closer-->

                 </div> <!-- close description-->


            </div> <!-- closses main body bg-->


            <div class="block-border">


            </div>

            <div class="block-profile">


            </div>

             <div class="block-profile2">


            </div>

             <div class="block-profile3">


            </div>
    </div>
<footer>
            <p>&copy; Sea fussion Development - All rights Reserved</p>
        </footer>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body {
    background-color:#fffcf4;   
}
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1110px;
    background-color:#343332;
}
.header-main{
    border-bottom: 44px solid #4f4f4e;
}
.header-nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.header-nav{
    line-height: 37px;
    margin-left:20px;

}
.header-nav ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:68px;
}
.header-nav ul li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans MT", "Gill Sans", "DejaVu Sans Condensed",                             Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.header-nav ul li a.active{

}

.header-nav ul li a:hover{

}
.main-body-background {
    display: block;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    width:790px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:429px;
    margin-top:106px;

}
.main-body-slideshow {
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    width:538px;
    height:301px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:241px;


}
.main-boddy-twitter{
    width:217px;
    height:383px;
    margin-left:549px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:block;
}
.main-boddy-descript{
    width:538px;
    height:74px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.main-boddy-descript p{
    padding-left:10px;
}
.main-boddy-descript h2{
    font-size:1.3em;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.block-border{
    margin-top:23.30px;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    height:49px;
    width:790px;
    margin-left:160px;
    display:block;

}
.block-profile{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
        display:inline-block;
    margin-left:160px;
}
.block-profile2{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:12px;
}
.block-profile3{
    margin-top:30px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:12px;
}
footer p {              
    font-size:.8em;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    line-height: 1.2; 
    color:#E3E3E3;  
}
footer {    
    padding: .3em 8%;
    margin-top:148px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px white; 
}

.clearfix:after {       
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}            
@media screen and (min-width:1400px){
    body {
    background-color:green; 
}
.main-body-background {
    display: block;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    width:1076px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:598px;
    margin-top:106px;

}
.main-body-slideshow {
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    width:741px;
    height:425px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:48px;


}
.main-boddy-twitter{
    width: 293px;
    height: 538px;
    margin-left: 747px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:block;
}
.main-boddy-descript{
    width:740px;
    height:101px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.block-border{
    margin-top:23.30px;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    height:49px;
    width: 1076px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    display:block;

}
.block-profile{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
        display:inline-block;
    margin-left:18px;
}
.block-profile2{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:154px;
}
.block-profile3{
    margin-top:30px;
    height:215.0px;
    width:253px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:154px;
}
.logo{
    width:540px;
    height:136px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){.main-boddy-twitter{
    display:none;
}
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:456px;
    background-color:#343332;
}
body {
    background-color:pink;  

}
.main-body-background {
    display: block;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    width:441px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:320px;
    margin-top:106px;

}
.main-body-slideshow {
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    width:383px;
    height:216px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-left:33px;
    margin-right:43px;


}
.main-boddy-descript{
    width:383px;
    height:68px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 33px;


}
.block-border{
    margin-top:23.30px;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    height:49px;
    width: 440px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display:block;

}
.block-profile{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:88px;
    width:102px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
        display:inline-block;
    margin-left:8px;
}
.block-profile2{
    margin-top:30.0px;
    height:88px;
    width:102px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:62px;
}
.block-profile3{
    margin-top:30px;
    height:88px;
    width:102px;
    background-color:#88bdcd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:62px;
}
.logo{
    width:221px;
    height:56px;
}
}
```

JS

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: A site example is YouTubes show more button on the description of videos, how it pushes other sections down to compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your height value for `main-boddy-descript` like this:

```
.main-boddy-descript {
    height:auto;
    min-height: 74px;
    /* other properties */
}
```

And do the same with `main-body-background` like this:

```
.main-body-background {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 429px;
    /* other properties */
}
```

Please follow the same procedure as above for your media queries too.

Here's a jsfiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/dzhoeo69/2/

Comment: oh  boy, I feel silly for not thinking of this. Thanks for the help though! really helpful>

Comment: Glad I could help moliminous

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've got a fixed height on the `div` with the class `.main-boddy-descript`. Change it to a `%` in oppose to `px`